# C++ Randomization and Loop Difficulties

Tags: c++, random

I'm trying to create a game where multiplication questions using numbers between 1 and 9 are repeatedly asked until someone makes a mistake. When they are wrong, the program should display "oops".

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{

srand (time(NULL));
int a= rand()%9+1;
int b= rand()%9+1;
int c;


while (c == a*b)

{


cout<<a<<" * "<<b<<"= ";
cin>>c;

}


    cout<<"oops";

return 0;
}
```

I'm having two difficulties. Firstly, the same "random" numbers are generated in the program. Secondly, when someone makes a mistake, the "oops" is not displayed.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Prefer the `<random>` header.

Comment: Look up what `srand` does in a manual.

Comment: Now that you've changed the code around, it's still likely you'll get a compiler warning, and very unlikely the while loop will be entered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing same numbers each time because you initialize them before the loop and then dont change them when user answers. To do this, generate new random value each time the loop is (re-)entered. You probably dont see "oops" because you program terminates instantly. To fix this, you can use `getch()` to wait for some imput before exiting.

I have fixed your code so study it and learn from the changes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    while (c == a*b)
    {
        a= rand()%9+1;
        b= rand()%9+1;

        cout<<a<<" * "<<b<<"= ";
        cin>>c;

    }
    cout<<"oops";
    getch();//Get some input so program does not terminate instantly
    return 0;
}
```

If you have any questions, feel free to leave comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed your random number generator, or you'll get the same random numbers each time.  A common practice is to seed the random number generator with the current time when the program starts, like:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Your program is exiting immediately after the `cout << "oops"` line.  Depending on your debugging environment, you might not see the final output even if it is placed on the console.  The final output might also be cached (and not put on the console immediately).  You could try adding a new line, like:

```
cout << "oops" << endl;
```

or adding an explicit call to prevent the program from exiting immediately.  In (say) Visual Studio under Windows, you can add a command like:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

before your `return 0` to prevent the debugging console from disappearing right away.  In other environments you won't have "PAUSE" available, but you could put an endless loop at the end, like `while (true) { /* do nothing */ }` just for debugging.

Finally, `rand` isn't considered to be a very good pseudo-random number generator, and nowadays most people like `random` (and `srandom(time(NULL))`) more.